# change css properties while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Basically I am trying to link my scrollbar to a progress meter on a page. There are multiple sections on each page so, Depending on where you are on the page, that correlates to which meter you want to run. I'm not so sure on how to start creating this, but can some point me in the right direction. Im currently using localscroll and ScrollTo plugins.

example:

Section 1 - meter is at 0%
Once you scroll through section 1 - meter is at 100%
section 2's meter starts - anther meter is at 0%
end of section 2 - meter is at 100%
and so on.

Thank you for your time,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the scrolltop with jQuery :

each time you will get an integer ( poistion of the scroll)...

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

you should divide a region on you page to "meter zone"

scolltop 1-20 = meter1

scolltop 20-40 = meter2

...